# Fixed element on Windows phone -workaround

Tags: css, windows-phone-7

I have a header-element which needs to be positioned to the top (`position:fixed; top:0;`).

The problem I have, is that even though the solution above works perfectly on desktop browsers and iOS browsers, it doesn't work on Windows Phone (7.5).

I read that WP 7.5 puts fixed elements to the top of the document, not screen.

Now the fixed header sticks to the top of the document and when scrolling down, it disappears from the screen as it is on the top of the document, when it should follow in the top of the screen, as it does normally in the iOS and desktop browsers.

Is there any workaround for this issue? I've already spent a good while on this issue, Googling around with no working result.

---

Here's my code:

```
<div id="header></div>

#header {
    height:50px;
    width:100%
    padding:13px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE on Windows 7.5 does not understand `position:fixed`. You should use `position:absolute` before it. 
Below is an updated code

```css
#header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100% padding: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```